# ASP.Net - Hide Sub Menu On Error Page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an `asp.net` website and on certain pages I have a sub menu displayed and others I don't. The thing in now, is that i want to hide my sub menu on my custom error page.

When I hit my custom error page, my URL does not change (e.g. user enters an invalid URL) and because of this I need to somehow look for the header or something on my page to hide it or not and I can't figure it out.

Code in my `Site.Master.cs` to hide sub menu:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var URL = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

    if (URL == "/Default" || URL == "/default.aspx" || Request.Url.ToString().Contains("Session") || Request.RequestContext.ToString().Contains("Page"))
    {
        this.Sidebar.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

HTML in my `Site.Master.cs` file for sub menu:

```
<div ID="Sidebar" runat="server" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs" style="padding-left: 0px">
     <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About us</a></li>
               <ul class="nav nav-stackedsub">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/testpage">test1</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/EmailPg">test2</a></li>
               </ul>
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/Session/pg1">Session</a></li>
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/EmailPg">Email</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Which looking at the above, the URL is my homepage or default it hides. It also hides if for all my session pages but this is because my URL contains the word 'Session'

Is there way to add to the above to also look for the heading of my error page.

If i need to do it via Javascript/jQuery in the `errorpage.aspx`, then that's also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your errorpage.aspx, you could probably just add

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("Sidebar").style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```

Or since the errorpage.aspx is most likely a special page rather different than the rest of your pages, you could consider not using a MasterPage for just that file.

Comment: The issue i have just remembered is that in my `Site.Master` file i have an `if` statement `<% if (Sidebar.Visible == false){ %>     <div>     <%}  else  { %>     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="padding-right: 0px">     <%} %>     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </div>` so i also need to find a way to overrite this also

Comment: A Site.Master file should be used for things that are consistently the same throughout your pages. I would move the `<div>` tag to the `<asp:content>` sections instead, since you're choosing these divs on a per-page basis anyway. Or you could not user your Site.Master file for just the errorpage.aspx and not have to worry about that.